# How do I use regular expression to match multiple instances of matching text when using capturing groups

Tags: regex

I have a fairly simple text string I'm trying to match using regular expression with capture groups.

```
BOS 6:15AM  BWI 7:49AM
```

I have written the following regular expression:

```
^(?<CITY>\S*?)\h*(?<TIME>\d{1,2}:\d\d)(?<AMPM>[AMP]{2})
```

that successfully matches the first City/Time text, but fails to match the second. You can see an example here at [Reg 101](http://regex101.com/r/fL5uQ2/1)

What do I have to do to make the regular expression match both City/Time groups. Ideally I would like to be able to match 1 to N pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the starting anchor `^` in your regex in-order to match also the second one. If you fail to remove the anchor , it would do the match on the string which was present at the line start only.

```
(?<CITY>\S*?)\h*(?<TIME>\d{1,2}:\d\d)(?<AMPM>[AMP]{2})
```

OR

```
(?<CITY>\S*?)\h*(?<TIME>\d{1,2}:\d{2})(?<AMPM>(?:[AP]M))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fL5uQ2/2)

Comment: @AvinashRaf Thanks for the response. I was spending my time adding ? and + to the end of the regex.  Perhaps I should have started at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really capture an endless pair at one time.
In your regex, you cant do `(your regex)+` because the
capture groups will be overwritten each iteration of the quantifier.

Dot-Net can do this, but not other engines.
Its best to do a while match to get the other pairs.
Oh and you should remove the anchor `^` or use a word boundry.

```
\b(?<CITY>\w+)\h+(?<TIME>\d{1,2}:\d[2})(?<AMPM>[AaPp][Mm])
```